# Unable to start XAMPP and Tomcat 8.0

Tags: xampp, tomcat8

I have a problem while starting the XAMPP server and also Tomcat 8.0.

I tried changing the ports, even though this error shows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well you should check if those ports are in use or not, and if are, stop what's using them?

Comment: Yeah it is rectified. But now the problem is while running the servlet which is been called from JSP. The error says THE RESOURCE FILE IS NOT FOUND

Comment: Well don't ask totally new questions in the comments. Maybe just delete this question and create a new one.